# Binary Decision Diagram library for windows

Tags: data-structures, binary-decision-diagram

After trying to get [jinc](http://www.jossowski.de/projects/jinc/jinc.html) compiled under windows and quickly running into hundreds of compiler errors I'm looking for a quality BDD library that will build for windows. Preferably in C or C++ but as long as I can bind to it I'm happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cudd is is good : http://vlsi.colorado.edu/~fabio/CUDD/ I have compiled it in Visual Studio 2005.

There seems to exist pre compiled binaries : http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~alanmi/research/soft/softPorts.htm

As an ex researcher, I can tell you that two years ago, Cudd was the best in class regarding efficiency.

Comment: Great that your answer includes instructions on how to get it building under windows, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I recently wrestled with installing the CUDD v2.4.2 in a Windows / Visual Studio environment.

There is documentation out there, but in my opinion none of it gives the complete picture of how to install the thing and get it working in non-Unix environments.  For example, how to address the issues with the Makefile, how to link to the *.a C archive files in your project, minor issues with the cpu_stats.c file, etc.  This is a shame because CUDD seems to be quite a powerful means of reducing complexity for many problems, such as integer programming.

I recently managed to get it going in VS 2010.  My blog details [here](http://technical-recipes.com/?p=329).

Answer (score 1):

Biddy is becoming better and better.. http://biddy.meolic.com/

OK, this is a subjective claim, because I am the main author of Biddy. However, while Biddy does not have so many functions and it does not
have so robust and improved memory management and it has not
been tested in so many projects as CUDD, it is a viable library.
By using it, you can help to improve it. My group is active and flexible
and we can implement any function you need.